# ListView: MultiSelect items with mouse drag

Tags: vb.net, listview

In ListView, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the item to select. But, I want to drag the mouse to select the items (like DataGridView). I tried this code (below) and I had a problem like this:

[image: My problem]

My code:

```
Private mouseDownLV As Boolean

Private Sub ListView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDown
    mouseDownLV = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseMove
    If mouseDownLV Then
        Try
            Dim i = ListView1.HitTest(e.Location).Item.Index
            ListView1.Items(i).Selected = True
        Catch ' ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseUp
    mouseDownLV = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a DataGridView with one column and no headers?

Comment: But the DataGridView is not as beautiful as ListView :((

Comment: Well I wasn't expecting that! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need to iterate through the currently displayed `ListViewItem` objects and  *toggle* the `Selected` property of the items that intersect with the mouse movement. Here's a way to achieve that:

Declare a class member named `startPoint`:

```vb
Private startPoint As Point
```

Handle the `MouseDown` event to set the starting position:

```vb
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDown
    Dim s = DirectCast(sender, ListView)

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso
        s.Items.Count > 1 Then
        startPoint = e.Location
    End If
End Sub
```

Handle the `MouseMove` event to *toggle* the `Selected` property:

```vb
Private Sub ListView1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseMove
    Dim s = DirectCast(sender, ListView)

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso s.Items.Count > 1 Then
        Dim selRect As New Rectangle(Math.Min(startPoint.X, e.Location.X),
                                    Math.Min(startPoint.Y, e.Location.Y),
                                    Math.Abs(e.Location.X - startPoint.X),
                                    Math.Abs(e.Location.Y - startPoint.Y))

        Dim cr = s.ClientRectangle

        'Toggle selection...
        For Each item In s.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).
            Where(Function(x) x.Bounds.IntersectsWith(cr))
            item.Selected = selRect.IntersectsWith(item.Bounds)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

A quick demo to check that:

[image: SOQ60585423A]

But what if you have many items where the size of the client area is not large enough to display them all and thus the vertical scrollbar is visible? You will get something like this:

[image: SOQ60585423A]

As you can see, the vertical scrollbar does not move and you won't be able to continue selecting/deselecting the hidden items. To fix that, we need some more code:

Import the signature of the [GetScrollPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollpos) function somewhere in your class:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
'...

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function GetScrollPos(hWnd As IntPtr,
                                    nBar As Orientation) As Integer
End Function
```

<sup>**Note:** Passing a `System.Windows.Forms.Orientation` value instead of an `Interger`.</sup>

Change the `MouseDown` event to:

```vb
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDown
    Dim s = DirectCast(sender, ListView)

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso
    s.Items.Count > 1 Then
        Dim vsp = GetScrollPos(s.Handle, Orientation.Vertical)
        Dim yOffset = s.Font.Height * vsp

        startPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y + yOffset)
    End If
End Sub
```

And the `MouseMove` event to:

```vb
Private Sub ListView1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseMove
    Dim s = DirectCast(sender, ListView)

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso s.Items.Count > 1 Then
        Dim vsp = GetScrollPos(s.Handle, Orientation.Vertical)
        Dim yOffset = s.Font.Height * vsp

        Dim selRect As New Rectangle(Math.Min(startPoint.X, e.Location.X),
                                    Math.Min(startPoint.Y - yOffset, e.Location.Y),
                                    Math.Abs(e.Location.X - startPoint.X),
                                    Math.Abs(e.Location.Y - startPoint.Y + yOffset))

        Dim cr = s.ClientRectangle

        'Toggle selection...
        For Each item In s.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).
            Where(Function(x) x.Bounds.IntersectsWith(cr))
            item.Selected = selRect.IntersectsWith(item.Bounds)
        Next

        'Scroll if needed...
        Dim p = s.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        Dim lvi = s.GetItemAt(p.X, p.Y)

        If lvi Is Nothing Then Return

        Dim fh = s.Font.Height

        If lvi.Index > 0 AndAlso (p.Y - lvi.Bounds.Height * 1.5) <= fh Then
            s.Items(lvi.Index - 1).EnsureVisible()
        ElseIf lvi.Index < s.Items.Count - 1 AndAlso
            (p.Y + lvi.Bounds.Height * 1.5) > (s.Height - fh) Then
            s.Items(lvi.Index + 1).EnsureVisible()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The outcome is:

[image: SOQ60585423C]

[Here](https://pastebin.com/vwnTUwBy) is VB.NET custom ListView control for this problem, and [another](https://pastebin.com/9TzmmfEJ) in C#.